# How to test if a transaction create a specific event using the trace api?

Tags: events, openethereum, transaction-trace, frontrunning, trace

I need to frontrun a transaction on a specific contract only if does a specific thing which is fired as an event once included in a block.

So how to get the event based on current contract state of an unconfirmed raw transaction or unconfirmed transaction hash using my full archival node?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @Undead8 no I didn’t.